# Read secrets Kubernetes from a spring batch deployed on a spring cloud dataflow

Tags: kubernetes, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

How can I read a Kubernetes secret in a Spring Batch deployed in a Spring Cloud dataflow in Kubernetes. The documentation is not very clear about this.

Comment: `The documentation is not very clear about this.`: Can you share which part of the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: This is the documentation about how to configure in spring cloud dataflow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_secret_references, but it's not telling how to read the secret in the spring batch deployed

Comment: ok thank you. From that section: `Secrets can be referenced and their entire data contents can be decoded and inserted into the pod environment as individual variables.` which means the secrets that you can define by setting properties like `deployer.<application>.kubernetes.secretRefs=testsecret` will be configured as environment variables in the Pod's environment. Once that in place, you can refer to those variables from your Spring Batch job using the Spring's `Environment` abstraction as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not specific to Spring Batch or Spring Cloud Dataflow, but what you can do is assign secrets to environment variables in your Kubernetes specification and read them from Spring's [Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) in your batch job.

Here is a quick example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-job-container
          image: my-image/my-job
          env:
            - name: MY_VAR
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: my-secret
                  key: my-secret-key
```

In the code of your Spring Batch job, you can use the environment abstraction from Spring framework and access the variable you need:

```
// somewhere in a Spring managed bean
@Autowired Environment environment;

// use this.environment to read the variable you need
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it will not work. I create the task in spring cloud dataflow and this tool will manage Kubernetes. I don't have access to the yaml configuration file. This is issue needs to be resolved by spring cloud dataflow configuration somehow.

Comment: In this case, your question is not related to Spring Batch. As I understand it now, it is rather how to read a Kubernetes secret in an application that is deployed to SCDF. `The documentation is not very clear about this.`: Can you share which part of the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: This is the documentation about how to configure in spring cloud dataflow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_secret_references, but it's not telling how to read the secret in the spring batch deployed

Comment: ok thank you. From that section: `Secrets can be referenced and their entire data contents can be decoded and inserted into the pod environment as individual variables.` which means the secrets that you can define by setting properties like `deployer.<application>.kubernetes.secretRefs=testsecret` will be configured as environment variables in the Pod's environment. Once that in place, you can refer to those variables from your Spring Batch job using the Spring's `Environment` abstraction as mentioned in the answer.